# How do I run a thread only once in an android application?

Tags: java, android-studio

Maybe this is a stupid question, I don't have much experience with android studio. Sorry for that.

In my app I have many activities which represent pages. In MainActivity I create a thread which always listens for something (it stays in loop). But whenever I return to the MainActivity page it creates another thread. If I only want to run it once, what are ways to do it?

I was thinking if maybe using a static variable to count how many times client is running, and stop it from creating another if there already is one.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Thread client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        client = new Thread(new CheckForOrders());
        client.start();
    .
    .
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread can only be run once under any circumstances.  What's likely happening is that you're creating a *new copy* of the thread every time your activity is destroyed and recreated on a configuration change (the most common config change being a device rotation.)

If you want to preserve a background thread between activity instances, you have two options:

1. If you want it to survive between different activities or when no activity is running, put it in a `Service`.
2. If you only need it to survive configuration changes, put it in a retained `Fragment`.

Comment: How do I put it in a service? Any good links I can read up on?

Comment: @Blackb3ard Two great places to start: [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and [this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+service).

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want one instance of the Thread you can declare it as static something like this:

```
private static Thread client = new Thread(new checkForOrders());
```

Comment: The danger of making it `static` is that it could keep running after all your components have been destroyed.